# Control effects on padding when copying a C++ POD

Tags: c++, alignment, padding

Padding is not specified in C++ standard. It is compiler and CPU dependent.
Manually avoid padding could lead to performance issues or worse.
So controlling what's in padding seems to be a more viable way to minimize undesirable side effects caused by padding, such as security.

What I want to do is to have padding of zero in an aligned POD. e.g. a templated function `template<typename T> T zero_padding(T const & pod);`

But there are problems.

1. If we do a direct `struct` copy, we don't know what will be done on padding, since C standard doesn't guarantee anything.
2. We can `memset` the structure, and then do a member-wise copy. But it seems to be structure-specific, and not easily done for template.

So I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

Comment: What is in the padding should never be read, so why does it matter? Your compiler may let you disable padding entirely.

Comment: @NeilKirk As I mentioned, for security reason. you can leak information through those padding.

Comment: Could you give a simple example of how this can occur? I'm just curious.

Comment: @NeilKirk https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL39-C.+Avoid+information+leak+in+structure+padding This has some info. But the solution seems to be manually do it or just using compiler-setting to avoid padding.

Comment: You will have to use a specific compiler which does the behavior you want.

Comment: You could try placement new. Create a memory buffer, memset it to what you want, and then create your struct on top of it. So long as every instance of the struct is on your special buffers (no stack copies), the padding should never be a sensitive value.

Comment: Crazy idea with no guarantees. Create a control struct as `mystruct test = {};` which should zero out all the members (at least ints. floats and pointers may not be binary zero which will mess this up). Now create memory buffer and memset to 0xFF and placement new a new struct. Copy your test struct onto your second struct. Use a char pointer to peek at each byte of the struct, looking for non-zero bytes. These are padding bytes. Record their position. Now you know which bytes to clear in your zero_padding. But if a padding was 0 it won't be detected..

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is such a problem. The data could come from anywhere, and at most you should only get 3 bytes with no context of what they mean, hardly a security leak.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the heart of their argument

"As a result of being uninitialized, padding bytes could have random data (sensitive data)."

I suggest it is much safer to clear sensitive data when you are done with it, than for all other code to worry about memory containing sensitive data.
You want sensitive data to have a controlled life time, leaving it laying around and not being controlled is weak.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memcpy` to copy the bytes of the structure. This will copy the padding bytes. Legality of `memcpy` is sort-of the whole thrust of the POD concept.

To ensure that the copy operation produces zeroed padding, ensure that every original object is initialized with zeroed padding. C++ does initialize padding bits of a POD to zero when performing value-initialization, i.e. if the initializer is `= T()` or in C++11, simply `{}`. Or if you prefer, you could use `memset`.

Comment: That is the same with copying the member individually. Simply, I want a way to change an existing struct's padding to all zeros.

Comment: @WiSaGaN How did you get such an existing struct in the first place? Merely having such a problem pretty much implies a security issue. (And, no, this is different from your two suggestions: copying members will certainly not copy padding, and copying the whole thing by simple assignment may or may not; there is no guarantee.)

Comment: Maybe I need to remove the security background in my question. I just want to find out whether there is a way to zero out all the padding easily. Seems the answer is no.

Comment: @WiSaGaN Nope. Actually I was wrong about member-wise copy; it can copy padding because the compiler can detect that you're copying a bunch of neighboring bytes and also decide to copy other bytes without semantic meaning. To stop that, you need to scatter the data in memory before copying to the destination, use `volatile`, or go through something like serialization+deserialization. On the other hand, preventing padding from ever being nonzero is pretty straightforward, at least in practical terms.